# Birt Crosstab Date Issue

Tags: report, birt

I have a crosstab where one of the groups contains a date. When the date is NULL, i want to display a space, anything I've tried including the code below on the expression for the binding name of the field. Yet it still displays Jan 1, 0001. How can I get it to display a space instead when the value is NULL?

```
if (["Group5"]["CP_EXPIRATION_DATE"]  == null ) {
  " ";
} else {
  dimension["Group5"]["CP_EXPIRATION_DATE"];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you can do this in the binding expression because the datatype is a Date, therefore a blank space can't be set as value. You could always use a script for this, although there might be a more elegant way:

Click your expiration date field onto the crosstab-> Script tab -> onRender -> Enter a script such

```
if (dimension["Group5"]["CP_EXPIRATION_DATE"]==null){
  this.setDisplayValue(" ")
}
```